# Resize layout dynamically based on children

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a button that if it is pressed shows a ListView with some data, the problem is that sometimes the list is cropped out like this:

[image]

and I don't know how to make de layout dynamic so the list does not crop, this is what I have:

```
 pullDownArrow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.pull_down_arrow);

 topMenuLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_top);

 topMenuContainer = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_top_container);

    listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);

    final int childNum = topMenuContainer.getChildCount() + listaCuentas.size();

    final int layoutHeight = (childNum * 37 + 70);

    final ResizeAnimation[] resizeAnimation = {null};

    pullDownArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            if (topMenuExpanded) {
                resizeAnimation[0] = new ResizeAnimation(topMenuLayout, dptopx(5));
                topMenuExpanded = false;
            } else {
                resizeAnimation[0] = new ResizeAnimation(topMenuLayout, dptopx(layoutHeight));
                topMenuExpanded = true;
            }


            resizeAnimation[0].setDuration(300);
            topMenuLayout.startAnimation(resizeAnimation[0]);
```

Comment: What do you mean with cropped? Is it that empty space in the middle?

Comment: @miguelarc no, I mean the last element of the list is cropped

Comment: One way you could simply solve this is to wrap your root layout in a scroll view. That way, when you have elements that are bigger than the viewport, the view will simply be scrollable. Because the views are occupying their space, meaning they are bigger than the view port, making one of them cropped.

Comment: @miguelarc the idea is not have a scroll because it can give conflicts with other scroll that is in the activity, i need it expandable based on the children

Comment: If it cannot be scrollable, either you decrease that gap between the two lists, or you have to decrease the height of each item, but either way can change on different screen densities.