# Delete Fragment from backstack and show actvity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have one activity, and three fragments, this is the life cycle:

1. Open app (Loads activity)
2. Press button (Loads fragment A)
3. Press another button (Loads fragment B)

***Activity -> Fragment A -> Fragment B***

What I want is that if I press the back button in **Fragment B** it shows me the **Activity**

How do I do it?

Right now, if I press the back button it shows me the **Fragment A**

**Edit:**
This is the way I call Fragment B

```
 public void changeFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

Comment: Your addToBackStack boolean is not needed, as it is not being used.

Comment: I know that. But that is not the issue, even with this code, **Fragment A** still shows when I press the back button @miguelarc

Comment: Is this function replacing the same id you are using for calling the fragment A in your activity?

Comment: You have more info [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui) about fragment transaction. Check under the fragment replace section

Comment: Yes, is replacing the same id. @miguelarc

Comment: Try removing the setTransition method. According the android docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction), FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN adds the fragment onto de stack.

Comment: If you don't need the backstack, simply doesn't addToBackStack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time, my solution was playing with the onBackPressed in the activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    FragmentManager fm = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ){
        for(int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
            fm.popBackStack();
        }
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the fragment B on top of fragment A, using `add()` in the `FragmentTransaction`. If you use `replace()` instead, the fragment A will be replaced with the fragment B, not adding it to the backstack, so that when you press back in your fragment B, the Activity is shown instead of fragment A. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18940937/7671879) for more details on how to replace a fragment.

Comment: Could you please help me with another question? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50724518/resize-layout-dynamically-based-on-children)